# Web2py SQLFORM update or insert depending on record existence checked at callback

Tags: python, web2py

I got stuck with the following challenge.

Can I use the callback function to decide whether to update a record or to insert a new one at form.process() call?

Simply put, I need a SQLFORM that users will fill with a textual reference identifier, and optionally a file to upload. That is, they should be able to upload a file with its reference or just insert a new reference and add its file later *but* through the same SQLFORM.

Model:

```py
db.define_table('t_object_occurence',
    Field('f_refid', type='string', label=T('Reference')),
    Field('f_object_id', db.t_object, label=T('Object')),
    Field('f_temp_file', type='upload', label=T('File'), autodelete=True)
    #more fileds
)
```

Whenever users select a file, some jQuery will update the ref id field based on the file name (which is formally defined).

View:

```html
{{if auth.has_permission('Object_occurence_UL'):}}
<h2>Add a new occurence</h2>
    {{=upload_form}}
{{pass}}
<h2>Latest occurences</h2>
{{=grid}}
<!-- some jQuery -->
```

Then, the following checks are performed (and others that are out of question's scope) through callback function called by form.process():

1. If a record with same ref id does not exist, then this form will have to generate a db insert. With or without the uploaded file.
2. If it does, 2 main cases:

   1. Either the existing record already got an uploaded file, then should raise a form error => that's done
   2. Or, if this record does not have its file, then I'd like it to get updated by the file form the upload filed.

Controller:

```py
def object_browse():
    obj = db.t_object(request.args[0])
    upload_form = SQLFORM(db.t_object_occurence, fields=['f_refid', 'f_temp_file'])
    # recall object ID in form parameters
    upload_form.vars.f_object_id = long(request.args[0])
    # perform field values checks with specific function analyse_occurence_data()
    if upload_form.process(onvalidation=analyse_occurence_data).accepted:
        if upload_form.vars.f_temp_file != '':
            response.flash = "File upload OK, occurence " + str(upload_form.vars.f_refid) + " added to repository"
        else:
            response.flash = "New forcasted occurence added " + str(upload_form.vars.f_refid)
        redirect(URL('object_browse', args=[str(obj.id)], user_signature=True))
    # display occurence list
    query = (db.t_object_occurence.f_object_id==long(request.args[0]))
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(...)
    return dict(upload_form=upload_form, grid=grid)
```

Checks callback function:

```py
def analyse_occurence_data(form):
    import types
    if isinstance(form.vars.f_temp_file, types.StringType):
        filename = None
    else:
        filename = form.vars.f_temp_file.filename
    occurence = form.vars.f_refid
    object_id = form.vars.f_object_id
    obj = db.t_object(object_id)
    # several checks and complementary form.vars.field = value
    potential_entry = db((db.t_object_occurence.f_refid==occurence)&(db.t_object_occurence.f_object_id==object_id)).select().first()
    if potential_entry is None:
        # let's insert a new record!
        return
    elif (filename is None) or (potential_entry.f_temp_file is not None):
        form.errors.f_temp_file = "The occurence "+occurence+" of "+obj.f_refid+" already exists in repository."
    elif potential_entry is not None:
            # THIS IS WHERE I'd like to decide to update instead of insert!
```

As my application cannot know before calling its callback if it will have to insert or update a record, I'm looking for the right instructions to give, so that my SQLFORM will do the right thing.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't just make a input form and an update form that the regular way to go... You seems to already have the id of the record you would update with complement information (attach file)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I think this is not going to work: 1st, I need a single form to keep users' life simple, their brain's already busy on more complex tasks, and they would not accept a system that is not at least as easy as the (very old) one they already have (you couldn't know). 2nd, I don't have the ID until I call the callback. JQuery could call some ajax and change the insert form to an update one... interesting but, 3rd, all in all, it would be more complex for me to code and maintain and I'm pretty sure we could do it the way I think. :)

Comment: Yes we can, I was just asking why you want to follow this path... Let me read the code carefully and I get back to you...

Comment: Not related, but better syntax Field('f_object_id', db.t_object, label=T('Object')), -> Field('f_object_id', 'reference t_object', label=T('Object')),

Comment: Where the difficult arise is how to make sure you will update the rigth record without id... You need to have the a set of field that can be refer as a composite primary key and a combination of value in these field should make them unique and consider a primary key or the reflexion of the surrogate id of the record...

Comment: Ok, I was miss guiding you in one of my comment that I deleted... You are right that the place where you have to insert or update is in the onvalidation function... Thought, I think that you will have to mute the insertion from form.process().accepted by using dbio=Flase, then you should be able to do insertion of update where you specified it in your analyse_occurence_data onvalidation function, try that and let me know if it solve your issue...

Comment: You will also need to redirect user from the onvalidation function because you are not allowed to return anything from this fuction, so you can't return the id of the inserted or updated record, except if you create "globals" variable for this purpose, but it is a bad idea... And if you redirect from this function, will have to make sure that you db.commit() to make sure your insert or update get apply to the backend...

Answer (score 1):

Here a working example that can help you adapt your above code :

```
def onvalidation_insert_or_update(form):
    row = db(db.mytable.f1 == form.vars.f1).select(db.mytable.ALL).first()
    if row is not None:
        id = row.id
        db(db.mytable.id == id).update(f2=form.vars.f2)
        session.flash = 'Record updated'
    else:
        id = db.mytable.insert(**form.vars)
        session.flash = 'Record inserted'
    db.commit()
    session.flash = 'Record inserted'
    redirect(URL(c='default', f='read_form', args=id))
    return


def basic_controller():
    form = SQLFORM(db.mytable)
    if form.process(dbio=False, onvalidation=onvalidation_insert_or_update).accepted:
        pass
    elif form.errors:
        response.flash = 'form has errors'
    else:
        response.flash = 'please fill the form'
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable)
    return dict(form=form, grid=grid)

def read_form():
    form = SQLFORM(db.mytable, record=request.args(0), readonly=True)  # readonly=True make form not modifiable
    return dict(form=form)
```

I can't attach the working app... But perhap, I can attach it with email if you ask your question to the web2py user google group, which is more convenient for this kind of question anyway.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for taking time. I had hard time to implement your suggestion as I had to revamp my complex processing. Even if your solution should work "as is", it seems to have side effects in my environment so that I can't make it work properly. As you suggest, I'm going to develop that point into the web2py user group.

Comment: Good, see you there, it gonna be easier then here the Q&A structure is hard to follow with your type of question... :)